which cartoon series had soundtrack similar to MI
I can't remember the cartoon series whose title track is similar to the mission impossible movie track. Can anyone help me out here, I am scratching my head over it for a long time!!
It use to come on TV during early 2000 and was very good. I am not sure but I guess it was related to a detective based theme.
Style: American
Soundtrack similarity: The tune is almost identical! If you'll listen to it maybe you'll remember.

did you remeber anything else? Like plot of the show, character's look, time frame you watched it etc etc.

I use to watch it in early 2000. plot of the cartoon was detective based but I am not sure..:/

Add the details in question itself and more the information you add, better the chances to get an answer.

American/european comic style or asian comic style? How similar was the music, completly or only some elements?

updated my question, thank u all for feedback

There was a Mission Impossible cartoon, is it possible that's what you're thinking of?



